# The name of the input field in being passed to action mentod instead of the value in text box in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, c#-4.0

I am new to MVC architecture. I am trying to do some enhancement in an existing code. There are already 2 date variables being passed to action method. I just need to pass email ID along with that. I did add an input field and passed the values with name and id. But the action method variable gets the name of the fields rather than the actual value entered in textbox. Oddly this works fine for other 2 existing date inputs.

Eg. If I enter abc@abc.com in email ID, the name,"emaildata" gets passed into variable in actionresult.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Effective Date</span>
            <input type="date" class="form-control popover-dismiss" name="efDate" id="effdate" data-toggle="popover" title="" 

data-content="Effective Date can't be emty!" data-placement="bottom" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Expiration Date</span>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="exDate" id="expDate" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Email ID</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emaildata" id="emaildata" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success tip pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add" onclick="@Url.Action("Create", "Home")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <button type="button" id="btnUpdateConfig" data-loading-text="updating..." class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="@Url.Action("UpdateConfig", "Home", new { emailID = "emaildata",efDate = "effDate", exDate = "expDate"})">
            Done..    <span class="badge badge-info">@Model.Count()</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

And the code behind

```
         [Ajax]
        [HttpGet]
        [HandleSessionTimeOut]
        public ActionResult UpdateConfig(string efDate, string exDate, string emailID, FormCollection FM)
        {

            try
            {

                    if (IsitDate(efDate, exDate))
                {
```

The values gets passed in here before it goes into action method.

```
$('#btnUpdateConfig').click(function () {

        var btn = $(this);

        if ($("#effdate").val().length != 0) {
            btn.button('loading');
            $.ajax({

            url: $(this).attr("onclick").replace("effDate", $("#effdate").val()).replace("expDate", $("#expDate").val()).replace("emaildata", $("#emaildata").toString()),

            type: 'GET',
             data: $("#emaildata").val(),


                success: function (response) {
                    $("#mainDiv").empty();
                    $("#mainDiv").html(response);
                },
                statusCode: {
                    401: function () {
                        window.location.href = '/WebUpload/Error/SessionTimeout';
                    }
                }
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Your submit button just redirect to another method - it does not POST your form! And `@Url.Action()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its passed to the view and you have added the initial values - they are not updated just because you edit the controls. You need a form and submit it.

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and learn the basics, in particular how to create a model, how to create a view based on your model using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods and how to post back the model.

Comment: Thanks for the response Stephen. I just wan't to add an email ID input. So I don't want to mess up more. I have added the app.js file above in code snippet. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is dreadful practice. And you code is riddled with errors. And your making both a redirect and an ajax call.

Comment: you should use ViewModel (Properties) for doing this in an efficient way.

Comment: Yes, its kinda messed up. But I don't want to re do all the work again. I just want to add the email ID and move on with this module. As I said earlier this is an enhancement to an existing code. The actual developer left the work some time back.